# how should i eliminate : while pulling the folder using adb

Tags: android, electron

How should i eliminate :  while pulling the folder using adb some of the folders contain special characters? Its not supporting in windows platform.

```
C:\Users\Vijay\Desktop\bug_report>adb pull /data/ingenic-log
pull: building file list...
pull: /data/ingenic-log/15(2017-02-16 16:56:00)/logcat.txt -> ./15(2017-02-16 16
cannot create '.\15(2017-02-16 16:56:00)\logcat.txt': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the whole filepath in inverted commas ("")

Comment: This is command am using to pull directory from android device "adb pull /data/ingenic-log ".In Android device directory has special characters in its name, windows refuse to create  a directory with special character while pulling the file from the device.

Comment: Are you interested in a specific file or a folder, If possible please post the whole path

Comment: @raktale This the command to list dir : adb shell ls -R /data/ingenic-log >filelist.txt 
dir structure:
/data/ingenic-log:

14(2017-02-16 16:32:09)

15(2017-02-16 16:56:00)



/data/ingenic-log/14(2017-02-16 16:32:09):

kmsg.txt

logcat.txt



/data/ingenic-log/15(2017-02-16 16:56:00):

kmsg.txt

logcat.txt